# What does the function predict of the Tensorflow Model do with a regression problem leveraging a RNN

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am working on a Time Series Problem and i trained a model
with finance data. The performance was very well during the training of the net.

Now I am asking how to predict FORWARD into the future
What is the outcome of the predict function of a new dataset using a Tensorflow model.The following snippet show the call of the predict function

```
def predict(self, data=None ):
                            
    model =  tf.keras.models.load_model(self.createModelFileName())
                    
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    feature_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
       
    data.loc[:, data.columns != self.feature] = scaler.fit_transform(data.loc[:, data.columns != self.feature])
    data[[self.feature]] = feature_scaler.fit_transform(data[[self.feature]])    
    inputs = data[1:] 
  
    inputs = np.expand_dims(inputs, axis=0)
    print(f'Shape data: {data}')
    print(f'Shape inputs: {inputs.shape}')        
        
    prediction = model.predict(inputs, 32, steps=5, verbose=1)
                   
    print(prediction.shape)
    
    data[[self.feature]] = feature_scaler.inverse_transform(data[[self.feature]])
    inputs = np.array(data[self.feature])
    
    prediction = prediction[0,:,:]        
    print(prediction.shape)    
    prediction = feature_scaler.inverse_transform(prediction)
                                                                
    return inputs, prediction
```

The plots i have made just show a prediction of the input in the past using a arbitrary shift but not a prediction into the future.

[image: EURUSD 1500 Datasets with shift 24 and input 128]

I know about the term Auto regressive and i also tried it out, by extending the input for the predict function with the last predicted values.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look on the last sequence index. Assuming your sequence dimension is 1:

```
prediction = prediction[:,-1,:]
```